# O que está errado neste relacionamento do AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, relacionamento, adonisjs

Estou tendo o seguinte erro quando  dou **adonis migration:run** :

```
    { error: relation "polo" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:604:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:401:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
From previous event:
    at Client_PG._query (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\postgres\index.js:260:12)
    at Client_PG.query (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:202:17)
    at C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\transaction.js:272:21
From previous event:
    at Client_PG.trxClient.query (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\transaction.js:269:34)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:146:36)
From previous event:
    at Runner.<anonymous> (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:213:19)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
From previous event:
    at Runner.queryArray (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:212:106)
    at C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:46:23
From previous event:
    at Runner.run (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:34:31)
    at SchemaBuilder.Target.then (C:\ckinfo\node_modules\knex\lib\interface.js:20:43)
  name: 'error',
  length: 163,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file:
   'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\catalog\\namespace.c',
  line: '426',
  routine: 'RangeVarGetRelidExtended' }
```

Polo.js
    'use strict'

```
/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Polo extends Model {

    //
    departamentos () {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/Departamento')
    }

    endereco () {
        return this.hasOne('App/Models/Endereco')
    }
}

module.exports = Polo
```

MIGRATION DO POLO

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class PoloSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('polos', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('nome')
      table.string('endereco')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('polos')
  }
}

module.exports = PoloSchema
```

Departamento.js

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Departamento extends Model {

    //

    telefones() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/Telefone')
    }

    polo() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Polo')
    }
}

module.exports = Departamento
```

MIGRATION DO DEPARTAMENTO

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class DepartamentoSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('departamentos', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.string('nome')
      table.string('gerente')
      table.integer('id_polo')
      .unsigned()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('polo')
      .onUpdate('CASCADE')
      .onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('departamentos')
  }
}

module.exports = DepartamentoSchema
```

Endereco.js

'

```
use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Endereco extends Model {



    polo () {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Polo')
    }
}

module.exports = Endereco
```

MIGRATION DO ENDEREÇO

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class EnderecoSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('enderecos', (table) => {
      table.increments()

      table
      .integer('polo_id')
      .unsigned()
      .references('id')
      .inTable('polo')
      .onUpdate('CASCADE')
      .onDelete('CASCADE')

      table.string('gix')
      table.string('rb')
      table.string('vm')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('enderecos')
  }
}

module.exports = EnderecoSchema
```

Comment: o nome que você deu foi **POLOS**, mas você chamou ele em outro arquivo como **POLO**, ai aparece o erro de que ele não existe

Comment: Olá, obrigado por responder. Acabei de corrigir e agora diz que POLOS nao existe

Answer (score 0):

O nome que você deu para tabela foi **polos**, porém nas migrations de departamento e endereço você colocou em `.inTable('polo')` como **polo** e não **polos** que é o nome da tabela de referencia.

Altere para `.inTable('polos')` e verifique se o erro ainda ocorre.